# How to relate children items with the parent item in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I'm stuck with a little problem with python and pandas dataframe.
How can I loop through the column and use the ‘Type’ data to relate the Children (Orange, Banana & Avocades) with the Parent ‘Fruit’ and the Children (Burger, Fries) with the parent ‘Fast-Food’?

```
+-----------+------+----------+-----------+
| Parent_ID | ID   | Type     | Name      |
+-----------+------+----------+-----------+
|           | 226  | Category | Fruit     |
|           | 2090 | Item     | Orange    |
|           | 2091 | Item     | Banana    |
|           | 2092 | Item     | Avocados  |
|           | 209  | Category | Fast-Food |
|           | 2097 | Item     | Burger    |
|           | 2099 | Item     | fries     |
+-----------+------+----------+-----------+
```

I want my dataframe just like below.

```
+-----------+------+----------+-----------+
| Parent_ID |  ID  |   Type   |   Name    |
+-----------+------+----------+-----------+
|           |  226 | Category | Fruit     |
|       226 | 2090 | Item     | Orange    |
|       226 | 2091 | Item     | Banana    |
|       226 | 2092 | Item     | Avocados  |
|           |  209 | Category | Fast-Food |
|       209 | 2097 | Item     | Burger    |
|       209 | 2099 | Item     | fries     |
+-----------+------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by checking where the `Type` column equals to `Category` and take the `cumsum` of the boolean series. Then use the result to [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `ID` and take the first one as as the `Parent_ID` for each group:

```
g = df.Type.eq('Category').cumsum()
df = df.assign(Parent_ID=df.groupby(g).ID.transform('first'))
df['Parent_ID'] = df.Parent_ID.where(df.ID.ne(df.Parent_ID)).fillna('')

    ID      Type       Name    Parent_ID
0   226  Category      Fruit          
1  2090      Item     Orange       226
2  2091      Item     Banana       226
3  2092      Item   Avocados       226
4   209  Category  Fast-Food          
5  2097      Item     Burger       209
6  2099      Item      fries       209
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a series with the forward-filled values of `ID` and then assign those values to the `Parent_ID` column when `Type == 'Item'`

```
new_parent = df.query('Type=="Category"').reindex(df.index).ID.ffill().astype(int)

df.loc[df.Type.eq('Item'), 'Parent_ID'] = new_parent[df.Type.eq('Item')]

df
# returns:
  Parent_ID    ID      Type       Name
0             226  Category      Fruit
1       226  2090      Item     Orange
2       226  2091      Item     Banana
3       226  2092      Item   Avocados
4             209  Category  Fast-Food
5       209  2097      Item     Burger
6       209  2099      Item      fries
```